# How to create a two-handle range slider?

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way, using SwiftUI, to create a Slider with 2 handles?

I'm working on a project that that requires settings a low and high point for a random value to be created between, and sliders seem to fit that need perfectly. I currently have it implemented as 2 separate sliders, but it would much rather have it 1 slider with 2 handles.

I've been searching and I cannot find any examples of it in SwiftUI, but I did find a webpage example of what I'm looking to do here: https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

Is this possible in iOS via SwiftUI?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've created a custom slider for you. I hope that's enough for your needs. Let me know if there is anything else I can do.

[image]

Slider:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

//SliderValue to restrict double range: 0.0 to 1.0
@propertyWrapper
struct SliderValue {
    var value: Double
    
    init(wrappedValue: Double) {
        self.value = wrappedValue
    }
    
    var wrappedValue: Double {
        get { value }
        set { value = min(max(0.0, newValue), 1.0) }
    }
}

class SliderHandle: ObservableObject {
    
    //Slider Size
    let sliderWidth: CGFloat
    let sliderHeight: CGFloat
    
    //Slider Range
    let sliderValueStart: Double
    let sliderValueRange: Double
    
    //Slider Handle
    var diameter: CGFloat = 40
    var startLocation: CGPoint
    
    //Current Value
    @Published var currentPercentage: SliderValue
    
    //Slider Button Location
    @Published var onDrag: Bool
    @Published var currentLocation: CGPoint
        
    init(sliderWidth: CGFloat, sliderHeight: CGFloat, sliderValueStart: Double, sliderValueEnd: Double, startPercentage: SliderValue) {
        self.sliderWidth = sliderWidth
        self.sliderHeight = sliderHeight
        
        self.sliderValueStart = sliderValueStart
        self.sliderValueRange = sliderValueEnd - sliderValueStart
        
        let startLocation = CGPoint(x: (CGFloat(startPercentage.wrappedValue)/1.0)*sliderWidth, y: sliderHeight/2)
        
        self.startLocation = startLocation
        self.currentLocation = startLocation
        self.currentPercentage = startPercentage
        
        self.onDrag = false
    }
    
    lazy var sliderDragGesture: _EndedGesture<_ChangedGesture<DragGesture>>  = DragGesture()
        .onChanged { value in
            self.onDrag = true
            
            let dragLocation = value.location
            
            //Restrict possible drag area
            self.restrictSliderBtnLocation(dragLocation)
            
            //Get current value
            self.currentPercentage.wrappedValue = Double(self.currentLocation.x / self.sliderWidth)
            
        }.onEnded { _ in
            self.onDrag = false
        }
    
    private func restrictSliderBtnLocation(_ dragLocation: CGPoint) {
        //On Slider Width
        if dragLocation.x > CGPoint.zero.x && dragLocation.x < sliderWidth {
            calcSliderBtnLocation(dragLocation)
        }
    }
    
    private func calcSliderBtnLocation(_ dragLocation: CGPoint) {
        if dragLocation.y != sliderHeight/2 {
            currentLocation = CGPoint(x: dragLocation.x, y: sliderHeight/2)
        } else {
            currentLocation = dragLocation
        }
    }
    
    //Current Value
    var currentValue: Double {
        return sliderValueStart + currentPercentage.wrappedValue * sliderValueRange
    }
}

class CustomSlider: ObservableObject {
    
    //Slider Size
    let width: CGFloat = 300
    let lineWidth: CGFloat = 8
    
    //Slider value range from valueStart to valueEnd
    let valueStart: Double
    let valueEnd: Double
    
    //Slider Handle
    @Published var highHandle: SliderHandle
    @Published var lowHandle: SliderHandle
    
    //Handle start percentage (also for starting point)
    @SliderValue var highHandleStartPercentage = 1.0
    @SliderValue var lowHandleStartPercentage = 0.0

    var anyCancellableHigh: AnyCancellable?
    var anyCancellableLow: AnyCancellable?
    
    init(start: Double, end: Double) {
        valueStart = start
        valueEnd = end
        
        highHandle = SliderHandle(sliderWidth: width,
                                  sliderHeight: lineWidth,
                                  sliderValueStart: valueStart,
                                  sliderValueEnd: valueEnd,
                                  startPercentage: _highHandleStartPercentage
                                )
        
        lowHandle = SliderHandle(sliderWidth: width,
                                  sliderHeight: lineWidth,
                                  sliderValueStart: valueStart,
                                  sliderValueEnd: valueEnd,
                                  startPercentage: _lowHandleStartPercentage
                                )
        
        anyCancellableHigh = highHandle.objectWillChange.sink { _ in
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
        anyCancellableLow = lowHandle.objectWillChange.sink { _ in
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    
    //Percentages between high and low handle
    var percentagesBetween: String {
        return String(format: "%.2f", highHandle.currentPercentage.wrappedValue - lowHandle.currentPercentage.wrappedValue)
    }
    
    //Value between high and low handle
    var valueBetween: String {
        return String(format: "%.2f", highHandle.currentValue - lowHandle.currentValue)
    }
}
```

Slider implementation:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var slider = CustomSlider(start: 10, end: 100)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Value: " + slider.valueBetween)
            Text("Percentages: " + slider.percentagesBetween)
            
            Text("High Value: \(slider.highHandle.currentValue)")
            Text("Low Value: \(slider.lowHandle.currentValue)")
            
            //Slider
            SliderView(slider: slider)
        }
    }
}

struct SliderView: View {
    @ObservedObject var slider: CustomSlider
    
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: slider.lineWidth)
            .fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
            .frame(width: slider.width, height: slider.lineWidth)
            .overlay(
                ZStack {
                    //Path between both handles
                    SliderPathBetweenView(slider: slider)
                    
                    //Low Handle
                    SliderHandleView(handle: slider.lowHandle)
                        .highPriorityGesture(slider.lowHandle.sliderDragGesture)
                    
                    //High Handle
                    SliderHandleView(handle: slider.highHandle)
                        .highPriorityGesture(slider.highHandle.sliderDragGesture)
                }
            )
    }
}

struct SliderHandleView: View {
    @ObservedObject var handle: SliderHandle
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: handle.diameter, height: handle.diameter)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.15), radius: 8, x: 0, y: 0)
            .scaleEffect(handle.onDrag ? 1.3 : 1)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .position(x: handle.currentLocation.x, y: handle.currentLocation.y)
    }
}

struct SliderPathBetweenView: View {
    @ObservedObject var slider: CustomSlider
    
    var body: some View {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: slider.lowHandle.currentLocation)
            path.addLine(to: slider.highHandle.currentLocation)
        }
        .stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: slider.lineWidth)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is amazing. Very easy to implement. Seriously thank you. Did you write this entirely on your own?

Comment: Your welcome! Yea, I once wrote a color wheel using SwiftUI where I also had to make a custom slider. So it was a pleasure to make a range slider out of it. ;)

Comment: is there a way to change the step of the slider so it only returns integers?

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for such good clean code.  One bug I noticed in the `restrictSliderBtnLocation` function you should use `min` and `max` like so:  `let xOffset = min(max(0, dragLocation.x), sliderWidth)
        calcSliderBtnLocation(CGPoint(x: xOffset, y: dragLocation.y))`  This will allow the slider to reach all the way to the min and max values and not stop before you can drag to the ends.  But otherwise amazing!

Comment: Really useful. In my app the sliders should not be able to cross each other, would this be possible and where would the fix go?

Comment: Hi, I'm having an issue making this work with the full width of the view, I've tried getting it working with GeometryReader but still having issues, has anyone managed to get this working, thanks for the cleanCode and the solution

Comment: @TallDane Did you find the solution to prevent the handles from crossing each other?

Comment: No, but I did not spend a lot of time on it. Always hard to read other peoples code. Was hoping other people would need this too. Would still love to see a solution that stops/bounces as the range start/ends converge.

Comment: I was able to use @culjo's solution below.

Answer (score 26):

This range slider will work with any width provided.

- It uses `GeometryReader` to get the slider width
- The slider is bounded by the value range and the thumbs handle cannot cross each other

[image]

RangeSliderView Usage

```
@State var sliderPosition: ClosedRange<Float> = 3...8
RangedSliderView(value: $sliderPosition, bounds: 1...10)
```

RangeSlideView Implementation

```
struct RangedSliderView: View {
    let currentValue: Binding<ClosedRange<Float>>
    let sliderBounds: ClosedRange<Int>
    
    public init(value: Binding<ClosedRange<Float>>, bounds: ClosedRange<Int>) {
        self.currentValue = value
        self.sliderBounds = bounds
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geomentry in
            sliderView(sliderSize: geomentry.size)
        }
    }
    
        
    @ViewBuilder private func sliderView(sliderSize: CGSize) -> some View {
        let sliderViewYCenter = sliderSize.height / 2
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                .fill(Color.nojaPrimary30)
                .frame(height: 4)
            ZStack {
                let sliderBoundDifference = sliderBounds.count
                let stepWidthInPixel = CGFloat(sliderSize.width) / CGFloat(sliderBoundDifference)
                
                // Calculate Left Thumb initial position
                let leftThumbLocation: CGFloat = currentValue.wrappedValue.lowerBound == Float(sliderBounds.lowerBound)
                    ? 0
                    : CGFloat(currentValue.wrappedValue.lowerBound - Float(sliderBounds.lowerBound)) * stepWidthInPixel
                
                // Calculate right thumb initial position
                let rightThumbLocation = CGFloat(currentValue.wrappedValue.upperBound) * stepWidthInPixel
                
                // Path between both handles
                lineBetweenThumbs(from: .init(x: leftThumbLocation, y: sliderViewYCenter), to: .init(x: rightThumbLocation, y: sliderViewYCenter))
                
                // Left Thumb Handle
                let leftThumbPoint = CGPoint(x: leftThumbLocation, y: sliderViewYCenter)
                thumbView(position: leftThumbPoint, value: Float(currentValue.wrappedValue.lowerBound))
                    .highPriorityGesture(DragGesture().onChanged { dragValue in
                        
                        let dragLocation = dragValue.location
                        let xThumbOffset = min(max(0, dragLocation.x), sliderSize.width)
                        
                        let newValue = Float(sliderBounds.lowerBound) + Float(xThumbOffset / stepWidthInPixel)
                        
                        // Stop the range thumbs from colliding each other
                        if newValue < currentValue.wrappedValue.upperBound {
                            currentValue.wrappedValue = newValue...currentValue.wrappedValue.upperBound
                        }
                    })
                
                // Right Thumb Handle
                thumbView(position: CGPoint(x: rightThumbLocation, y: sliderViewYCenter), value: currentValue.wrappedValue.upperBound)
                    .highPriorityGesture(DragGesture().onChanged { dragValue in
                        let dragLocation = dragValue.location
                        let xThumbOffset = min(max(CGFloat(leftThumbLocation), dragLocation.x), sliderSize.width)
                        
                        var newValue = Float(xThumbOffset / stepWidthInPixel) // convert back the value bound
                        newValue = min(newValue, Float(sliderBounds.upperBound))
                        
                        // Stop the range thumbs from colliding each other
                        if newValue > currentValue.wrappedValue.lowerBound {
                            currentValue.wrappedValue = currentValue.wrappedValue.lowerBound...newValue
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder func lineBetweenThumbs(from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint) -> some View {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: from)
            path.addLine(to: to)
        }.stroke(Color.nojaPrimary, lineWidth: 4)
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder func thumbView(position: CGPoint, value: Float) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            Text(String(value))
                .font(.secondaryFont(weight: .semibold, size: 10))
                .offset(y: -20)
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                .foregroundColor(.nojaPrimary)
                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.16), radius: 8, x: 0, y: 2)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
        }
        .position(x: position.x, y: position.y)
    }
}
```

> There are some improvements that can be added
> e.g adding a step property or
> also implementing the slider with a generic init to support Int, Float and other number types
> use `ViewBuilder` to build a custom label for the slider

Comment: This one's good, just a small adjustment to account for the right padding on short slide bounds: `let sliderBoundDifference = sliderBounds.count - 1`

Comment: Agree - this one is probably the best starting point. I got it working in my App after some minor changes. @Đỗ Long Thành has done some good work in making the control embeddable, but I could not get his code (below) to work.

Comment: It's working great, and what about adding steps for the slider, for example, adding five for each step or movement?

Comment: Awesome! FYI - you don't need `@ViewBuilder` in any of those places. In `sliderView()`, you just need to return the `ZStack` explicitly since you have more than one line of code (`return` is only implied if a func has only one line [and in @ViewBuilders]).

Comment: Great example of doing things in SwiftUI.

Comment: For "leftThumbLocation", why do we need "currentValue.wrappedValue.lowerBound == Float(sliderBounds.lowerBound)"? why not just do "let leftThumbLocation: CGFloat = CGFloat(currentValue.wrappedValue.lowerBound - Float(sliderBounds.lowerBound)) * stepWidthInPixel"

Answer (score 3):

[image: Preview of Range slider]

I modified the code from @culjo. This code supports `preview` and the logical parts are moved to `viewModel`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct RangeSlider: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    @State private var isActive: Bool = false
    let sliderPositionChanged: (ClosedRange<Float>) -> Void

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            sliderView(sliderSize: geometry.size,
                       sliderViewYCenter: geometry.size.height / 2)
        }
        .frame(height: ** insert your height of range slider **)
    }

    @ViewBuilder private func sliderView(sliderSize: CGSize, sliderViewYCenter: CGFloat) -> some View {
        lineBetweenThumbs(from: viewModel.leftThumbLocation(width: sliderSize.width,
                                                            sliderViewYCenter: sliderViewYCenter),
                          to: viewModel.rightThumbLocation(width: sliderSize.width,
                                                           sliderViewYCenter: sliderViewYCenter))

        thumbView(position: viewModel.leftThumbLocation(width: sliderSize.width,
                                                        sliderViewYCenter: sliderViewYCenter),
                  value: Float(viewModel.sliderPosition.lowerBound))
        .highPriorityGesture(DragGesture().onChanged { dragValue in
            let newValue = viewModel.newThumbLocation(dragLocation: dragValue.location,
                                                      width: sliderSize.width)
            
            if newValue < viewModel.sliderPosition.upperBound {
                viewModel.sliderPosition = newValue...viewModel.sliderPosition.upperBound
                sliderPositionChanged(viewModel.sliderPosition)
                isActive = true
            }
        })

        thumbView(position: viewModel.rightThumbLocation(width: sliderSize.width,
                                                         sliderViewYCenter: sliderViewYCenter),
                  value: Float(viewModel.sliderPosition.upperBound))
        .highPriorityGesture(DragGesture().onChanged { dragValue in
            let newValue = viewModel.newThumbLocation(dragLocation: dragValue.location,
                                                      width: sliderSize.width)
            
            if newValue > viewModel.sliderPosition.lowerBound {
                viewModel.sliderPosition = viewModel.sliderPosition.lowerBound...newValue
                sliderPositionChanged(viewModel.sliderPosition)
                isActive = true
            }
        })
    }

    @ViewBuilder func lineBetweenThumbs(from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                .fill(** insert your color **)
                .frame(height: 4)

            Path { path in
                path.move(to: from)
                path.addLine(to: to)
            }
            .stroke(isActive ? ** insert your color ** : ** insert your color **,
                    lineWidth: 4)
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder func thumbView(position: CGPoint, value: Float) -> some View {
     Circle()
        .frame(size: .rangeSliderThumb)
        .foregroundColor(isActive ? ** insert your color ** : ** insert your color **)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .position(x: position.x, y: position.y)
        .animation(.spring(), value: isActive)
    }
}

extension RangeSlider {
    final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var sliderPosition: ClosedRange<Float>
        let sliderBounds: ClosedRange<Int>

        let sliderBoundDifference: Int

        init(sliderPosition: ClosedRange<Float>,
             sliderBounds: ClosedRange<Int>) {
            self.sliderPosition = sliderPosition
            self.sliderBounds = sliderBounds
            self.sliderBoundDifference = sliderBounds.count - 1
        }

        func leftThumbLocation(width: CGFloat, sliderViewYCenter: CGFloat = 0) -> CGPoint {
            let sliderLeftPosition = CGFloat(sliderPosition.lowerBound - Float(sliderBounds.lowerBound))
            return .init(x: sliderLeftPosition * stepWidthInPixel(width: width),
                         y: sliderViewYCenter)
        }

        func rightThumbLocation(width: CGFloat, sliderViewYCenter: CGFloat = 0) -> CGPoint {
            let sliderRightPosition = CGFloat(sliderPosition.upperBound - Float(sliderBounds.lowerBound))
            
            return .init(x: sliderRightPosition * stepWidthInPixel(width: width),
                         y: sliderViewYCenter)
        }

        func newThumbLocation(dragLocation: CGPoint, width: CGFloat) -> Float {
            let xThumbOffset = min(max(0, dragLocation.x), width)
            return Float(sliderBounds.lowerBound) + Float(xThumbOffset / stepWidthInPixel(width: width))
        }

        private func stepWidthInPixel(width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
            width / CGFloat(sliderBoundDifference)
        }
    }
}

struct RangeSlider_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RangeSlider(viewModel: .init(sliderPosition: 2...8,
                                     sliderBounds: 1...10),
                    sliderPositionChanged: { _ in })
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrapping the slider in a V/HStack messes up the control for me.  What does '.frame(size: .rangeSliderThumb)' do?

Comment: This is the best one, because its width is adaptable to the View container it is presented in, and also because its gestures work inside SwiftUI Previews.

Comment: The `self.sliderBoundDifference = sliderBounds.count - 1` you should check – I removed the -1 because then I cannot slide to the max value.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is older, but for any future reference, the above answers did not work well with negative numbers in my experience. Here is the code I ended up using.

```
struct RangeSliderView: View {
    @Binding var value: ClosedRange<Int>
    let bounds: ClosedRange<Int>
    
    @State private var viewSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    
    @State private var leftX: CGFloat = 11
    
    var body: some View {
        let pixelsPerStep = (viewSize.width - 22) / CGFloat(bounds.count - 1)
        let offset = -bounds.lowerBound
        ZStack {
            // Size
            GeometryReader { geo in
                Color.clear
                    .onAppear {
                        viewSize = geo.size
                    }
            }
            
            // Line
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(AppColors.contrast)
                .frame(width: viewSize.width, height: 6)
                .cornerRadius(4)
            
            // Left
            slider(
                bounds: bounds,
                pixelsPerStep: pixelsPerStep,
                offset: offset,
                viewMid: viewSize.height / 2,
                value: $value,
                isLower: true
            )
            
            // Right
            slider(
                bounds: bounds,
                pixelsPerStep: pixelsPerStep,
                offset: offset,
                viewMid: viewSize.height / 2,
                value: $value,
                isLower: false
            )

        }
    }
    
    private struct slider: View {
        let bounds: ClosedRange<Int>
        let pixelsPerStep: CGFloat
        let offset: Int
        let viewMid: CGFloat
        @Binding var value: ClosedRange<Int>
        let isLower: Bool
        @State private var sliderX: CGFloat = 11
        @State private var recentMove = false
        @State private var hideNow = false
        
        
        var body: some View {
            if hideNow {
                Color.clear
            } else {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(isLower ? Color(red: 0.5, green: 0.1, blue: 0.15) : Color(red: 0.7, green: 0.15, blue: 0.25))
                    .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
                    .position(x: sliderX, y: viewMid)
                    .highPriorityGesture(DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ drag in
                            var location = Int(round((drag.location.x - 11) / pixelsPerStep)) - offset
                            location = max(isLower ? bounds.lowerBound : value.lowerBound + 1, min(isLower ? value.upperBound - 1 : bounds.upperBound, location))
                            
                            value = isLower ? location...value.upperBound : value.lowerBound...location
                            sliderX = CGFloat((isLower ? value.lowerBound : value.upperBound) + offset) * pixelsPerStep + 11
                            
                            if !recentMove {
                                withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.2)) {
                                    recentMove = true
                                }
                                
                                withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.2).delay(1)) {
                                    recentMove = false
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    )
                    .onChange(of: pixelsPerStep) { pix in
                        sliderX = CGFloat((isLower ? value.lowerBound : value.upperBound) + offset) * pix + 11

                    }
                    .overlay {
                        let half = (bounds.upperBound + offset) / 2
                        
                        let lowerCase: Bool = isLower && (value.upperBound + offset) > half
                        let upperCase: Bool = !isLower && (value.lowerBound + offset) < half
                        
                        let lowerOut = min(sliderX, (pixelsPerStep * CGFloat(value.upperBound + offset)) - 10)
                        let upperOut = max(sliderX, (pixelsPerStep * CGFloat(value.lowerBound + offset)) + 40)
                        
                        let x = lowerCase ? lowerOut : upperCase ? upperOut : sliderX

                        Text(String(isLower ? value.lowerBound : value.upperBound))
                            .opacity(recentMove ? 1 : 0.5)
                            .scaleEffect(recentMove ? 1.5 : 1)
                            .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .bold))
                            .padding(8)
                            .background(.black.opacity(recentMove ? 1 : 0))
                            .cornerRadius(4)
                            .position(x: x, y: viewMid - (recentMove ? 28 : 18))
                    }
                    .zIndex((!isLower && value.upperBound == bounds.upperBound) ? 0 : 2)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
    @State private var value: ClosedRange<Int> = ClosedRange(uncheckedBounds: (-40, 50))
    let bounds: ClosedRange<Int> = ClosedRange(uncheckedBounds: (-50, 70))
    RangeSliderView(value: $value, bounds: range)
```

[Slider demo on iPhone 14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L1xH.gif)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs a stepped version - I used [culjo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71910078/2242359)'s great answer just using steps (Int) instead stemless (Float) and cleaned up a bit:

```swift
struct RangedSliderView: View {
    let currentValue: Binding<ClosedRange<Int>>
    let sliderBounds: ClosedRange<Int>

    public init(value: Binding<ClosedRange<Int>>, bounds: ClosedRange<Int>) {
        self.currentValue = value
        self.sliderBounds = bounds
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geomentry in
            sliderView(sliderSize: geomentry.size)
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder private func sliderView(sliderSize: CGSize) -> some View {
        let sliderViewYCenter = sliderSize.height / 2
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(height: 4)
            ZStack {
                let sliderBoundDifference = sliderBounds.count
                let stepWidthInPixel = CGFloat(sliderSize.width) / CGFloat(sliderBoundDifference)

                // Calculate Left Thumb initial position
                let leftThumbLocation: CGFloat = currentValue.wrappedValue.lowerBound == sliderBounds.lowerBound
                    ? 0
                    : CGFloat(currentValue.wrappedValue.lowerBound - sliderBounds.lowerBound) * stepWidthInPixel

                // Calculate right thumb initial position
                let rightThumbLocation = CGFloat(currentValue.wrappedValue.upperBound) * stepWidthInPixel

                // Path between both handles
                lineBetweenThumbs(from: .init(x: leftThumbLocation, y: sliderViewYCenter), to: .init(x: rightThumbLocation, y: sliderViewYCenter))

                // Left Thumb Handle
                let leftThumbPoint = CGPoint(x: leftThumbLocation, y: sliderViewYCenter)
                thumbView(position: leftThumbPoint, value: currentValue.wrappedValue.lowerBound)
                    .highPriorityGesture(DragGesture().onChanged { dragValue in

                        let dragLocation = dragValue.location
                        let xThumbOffset = min(max(0, dragLocation.x), sliderSize.width)

                        let newValue = sliderBounds.lowerBound + Int(xThumbOffset / stepWidthInPixel)

                        // Stop the range thumbs from colliding each other
                        if newValue < currentValue.wrappedValue.upperBound {
                            currentValue.wrappedValue = newValue...currentValue.wrappedValue.upperBound
                        }
                    })

                // Right Thumb Handle
                thumbView(position: CGPoint(x: rightThumbLocation, y: sliderViewYCenter), value: currentValue.wrappedValue.upperBound)
                    .highPriorityGesture(DragGesture().onChanged { dragValue in
                        let dragLocation = dragValue.location
                        let xThumbOffset = min(max(CGFloat(leftThumbLocation), dragLocation.x), sliderSize.width)

                        var newValue = Int(xThumbOffset / stepWidthInPixel) // convert back the value bound
                        newValue = min(newValue, sliderBounds.upperBound)

                        // Stop the range thumbs from colliding each other
                        if newValue > currentValue.wrappedValue.lowerBound {
                            currentValue.wrappedValue = currentValue.wrappedValue.lowerBound...newValue
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder func lineBetweenThumbs(from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint) -> some View {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: from)
            path.addLine(to: to)
        }.stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 4)
    }

    @ViewBuilder func thumbView(position: CGPoint, value: Int) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            Text(String(value))
                .font(.callout.bold())
                .offset(y: -20)
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.16), radius: 8, x: 0, y: 2)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
        }
        .position(x: position.x, y: position.y)
    }
}
```